# I am trying to add Linq result in Datatable but getting Error

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

```
dtConvertCSVtoDataTable = ConvertCSVtoDataTablex(file.FullName, file.Extension);
               IEnumerable<DataRow> results = from d1 in (dtConvertCSVtoDataTable[0]).AsEnumerable()
                                              join d2 in dtConvertCSVtoDataTable[1].AsEnumerable() on d1["Email Address"] equals d2["Email Address"]
                                              select new DataRow
                                              {
                                                   d1["Email Address"]

                                               };

               DataTable CombinedDataTable = new DataTable();
```

I am trying to add Linq result in Datatable but getting error :Cannot initialize type 'System.Data.DataRow' with a collection initializer because it does not implement 'System.Collections.IEnumerable'

Comment: try this: `( .... select d1).CopyToDataTable();`

Answer (score 0):

The syntax used to initialize DataRow is incorrect.. It generally looks like

```
select new <Type>
{
    <Property> = <Value>
}
```

The way you have your code,

```
select new <Type>
{
    <Value>
}
```

compiler thinks you are trying to initialize a collection, which DataRow is **not**, and hence the error.

Comment: thanks for you answer i have tried as you said, added email=d1["Email Address"] but it say DataRow does not contain definition for email